# error in the window getting the number -172492288 at the end of the while loop

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int *elementShifter(int[], int);



int main()

{

    int SIZE = 50;
    int array[SIZE];
    ifstream infile("Gradelist.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int count = -1,data=0;

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        count++;
        if (count < 0 || count > 50)
        return -1;
        else
        {
        infile >> array[count];

        }
        cout << array[count] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    int *s=elementShifter(array, count);

    for (int i = 0; i <=count; i++)
    {
        cout << *s << endl;
        s++;

    }
    return 1;

}

int *elementShifter(int arr[], int size)

{

    int *newArr = new int[size + 1];
    newArr[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

    {
    newArr[i+1]=arr[i];
    }

    return newArr;

}
```

I just cannot figure out why i am getting this number here

Comment: Do you really need to use pointers here? Using C arrays in C++ is trouble most of the time, and turmoil if not used carefully. Consider `std::vector`. For example, variable-length C arrays are not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: yes its part of our assignment to use a pointer

Comment: `newArr[i+1]=arr[i];` walks off the end of the array and invokes undefined behaviour. **Be extremely careful when using indexes**. The responsibility for not making mistakes is 100% on you, the programmer. The compiler will not warn or fuss if you make a mistake, it will do as told.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're stuck in a C+ course. Hope you survive without absorbing too many bad habits.

Comment: Tip: If you have an `if` with a `return` in it that will always trip, don't bother with an `else`. That's implicit. You can save a level of indentation and reduce clutter. That being said, not sure how `count < 0` could ever be true in this code.

Comment: Can you explain what the point of `elementShifter` is? It's far from clear. In your output loop you just dump the same value a bunch of times. Hint: `s[i]`.

Comment: so the element shifter is just to make the array one element bigger which is the point of this assignment, so it takes the values of the array and and places them back into the array with the first value stored being 0, and the array one size bigger

Comment: I'd expect to see that inside your input loop, and I'd also expect to see your original array allocated dynamically (e.g. `new[]`). Are you adding new data to the start or the end of the array? By "shift" you might mean "add to front".

Comment: not really a shift its just adding one element to the start of the array.

Comment: That's what's called "unshifting" as opposed to "push" which adds to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is reworked into slightly more idiomatic C++, but there's stuff here that might not fly in whatever course you're in, so adapt accordingly:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

// using namespace std; is a bad habit to get into, that prefix
// exists for an important reason: Code separation

// Tip: If you define before you reference a function in your code,
//      there is no need for a separate declaration.

// Note use of const on arguments that are not mutated
void unshift(int*& array, size_t& size, const int elem) {
  int *resized = new int[++size];

  // Insert at the start of the array
  resized[0] = elem;

  // Copy the remainder
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    resized[i] = array[i-1];
  }

  // Don't forget to release the old memory or you have a leak
  delete[] array;

  // Since the pointer is passed in as a reference, easy to swap it
  array = resized;
}

int main() {
  size_t size = 1; // size_t is often used for "size"-type args
  int *array = new int[size];

  std::ifstream infile("Gradelist.txt");

  if (!infile) {
    // Use std::cerr for errors.
    std::cerr << "File not found" << std::endl;

    return -1;
  }

  // infile evaluates as true so long as it has data to read.
  while (infile) {
    // You already have a count, it's "size"
    if (size> 50) {
      return -1;
    }

    int input;
    infile >> input;

    // This function takes mutable arguments, so they change via
    // references.
    unshift(array, size, input);
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
  }

  // Take out the trash
  delete[] array;

  // Return zero on success, non-zero on failure.
  return 0;
}
```

Of course a lot of this code goes away if you can use `std::vector<int>` and `push_back()`, but if you need to learn how to do this at a low-level, here you are with pointers and all the mess they create.

The goal in modern C++ is to avoid using pointers and instead lean heavily on the Standard Library to help you out.